# What program, software, or coding languages to schedule jobs, executable programs

Tags: windows, scheduling

What programs, softwares or coding languages to schedule jobs or executable programs. It would be great if this software can provide FTP access to extract data from a CRM also.

Schedule jobs or executable programs on a daily, monthly, or weekly basis?

- operating system: windows
- task is to run a program that I build either via excel vba, vb.net or python executable
- Schedule it to run daily, weekly or monthly by itself.

Comment: What operating system? All *nix variants - Linux, OS X, the BSDs, the commercial licensed Unix systems etc - have a cron implementation.  Windows had a task scheduler last time I used it, but that was 18 years ago... As to actually what script/program/whatever to schedule to run via whatever method, that comes down to what operating system and what task?

Comment: You need to be much more specific.

Comment: operating system - windows, task is to run a program that I build either via excel vba, vb.net or python executable. Schedule it to run daily, weekly or monthly by itself. What is the most efficient way ?  Is window scheduler best or other software or using a programming language to build it from scratch ?

Comment: "What is the most efficient way?" – Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. So please understand we read your question just that way: asking us to recommend you a software that fits your requirements. As a scheduler doesn't "provide FTP access" anyway, the Windows scheduler should fit, as @ivanivan already pointed out.

Comment: @Izzy - Ok sorry about that, thanks for pointing it out.  I think I might just try window scheduler. How about goanywhere software. I used it before but never gotten to see or know all of it's function and abilities.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a (voluntary) Windows user – only use it at customers' sites when I have to :) You'll have to wait until someone posts an answer. "How does X serve my purpose" is another type of question we don't deal with here, by the way ;)